# Who touched my file?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, procmon

On Windows 10, my build process is *copying* a read-only file to several different locations. once in a few builds, the original file becomes writable and its "modified date" updates.

I'm trying to find which process or command touches the file. Are there any methods to do that? Here's my unlucky experience with sysinternals Process Monitor (ProcMon):
Filter setting:

[image: ProcMon filter settings]

Note, the only filters are for the file path - I've deleted all the defaults. So, nothing should be hidden by ProcMon.

Result:

[image: ProcMon run]

There is a clear WriteFile operation. Is there any reason why the system would touch the file's date?

I've posted the question here since it seems like a file system issue.

Comment: When the date is modified, does the file's contents change too? A hash (crc/md5/etc) is different?

Comment: No, file remains the same.

Comment: Assuming your filters in procmon are set correctly, the only reason I can think of why procmon doesn't show you what happened is because it's not set at the right [altitude](http://fsfilters.blogspot.com/2012/04/useful-tools-for-file-system-developers.htm). Note that this would also mean that the lower level driver doesn't pass the event up to the chain. All unlikely but it's something you might want to try.

Comment: ProcMon doesn't show which file was changed, only directories. All my filters are set correctly.

Comment: ProcMon shows all file activity, you’re not using it right if you aren’t seeing the event, or the event didn’t happen.

Comment: Agree with @Appleoddity - if procmon is not showing you file activity, you are not using it right. Can you post a screenshot of your filters/output?

Comment: Before I post a screenshot, let me first ask this: is there a ProcMon column that displays the files that are read/written? The closest I see is the image path of the process, or the path in which the process is working - but not the filename itself.

It also can't be seen in the event properties.

Comment: Ok, posted a screenshot of the filter settings in the question.
I capture the event of copying C:\temp.txt into another location (actually did a ctrlC+ctrlV on the file). I get a bunch of events, none of which tells me there was an operation on a file named temp.txt.

Comment: The filter `path is C:\` will only show paths that are **exactly** C:\. You probably mean to use the condition *begins with.* If you want to find operations on the file temp.txt, use the condition *contains* "temp.txt"

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've modified the question and added some pics to show the mystery.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator makes in important point. For example `\\localhost\f$` and `\\?\F:` won't show up.

Comment: @Seth, I specified an explicit file name - that's the file I'm interested in examining

Comment: Yes and we're both telling you there are other paths that allow you to access that file. Use one of the above examples and access the file that way and it won't show up. Which is why you probably want to use either just the file name or the path as a "ends with" filter.

Comment: Thanks @Seth and Twisty-impersonator, question updated, new pics uploaded. There is a WriteFile out of nowhere...